# Interrupted highlighting animation

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have a dynamic form of sorts where clicking the add button adds a row to a table of fields, and the remove button takes away a row. 
So far I have this working, and I am using the Highlight animation from jQuery UI to draw attention to a newly inserted row. The problem is, if I add rows too fast, the highlight animation of the new rows can freeze/hang. Here's a screencap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUJqr.png

And here's a jsbin of my code:
http://jsbin.com/ogaziv/3/edit

If you uncomment what I have commented out in the js, this fixes the problem, but is there any reason why I'm running into this glitch?
I'm relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery in general, but this seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting `$('.dyn_combo_qty tr:last td')` which selects the last `tr` element, by adding a new `tr` the last `tr` now is 1 to the last and this stops it's animation.

http://jsbin.com/ogaziv/7/edit

Comment: From that bin, if I comment out the background bit, I still run into the same problem.
I've taken out the background color bit and replaced that selector to `new_elem`, but my freezing glitch still happens.

http://jsbin.com/ogaziv/8/edit

Comment: @actaeon yes, that link was a suggestion, not a solution.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to get at is, is there a more elegant way to get around this glitch/am I going about this the wrong way?
It just doesn't seem to make sense that I have to edit the CSS to force the animations to complete.